# Running as infinite loop

Tags: c++

When I try to call this function and provide a value to variable grade other than integer, the do-while loop kept on executing and don't even prompt for an input to the variable of type char. Kindly help me to figure out why loop kept on executing.

```
//User Input function
int userInput(){
    int grade,question;
    char choice='y';
    srand(time(0));
    do{
        //displayMenu();
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Please select grades, use number 1 to 5: ";
        cin>>grade;
        /*if(grade<1 || grade>5){
            cout<<"You have entered an invalid grade!"<<endl;
        }

        else{
            cout<<"Enter number of questions you want to generate: ";
            cin>>question;
            while(question<1){
                cout<<endl;
                cout<<"You have entered an invalid number"<<endl;;
                cout<<"Enter number of questions you want to generate: ";
                cin>>question;
                }
            cout<<endl;
            questionGenerator(grade,question);
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Press n/N to Quit or Press any key and then Enter";
            cin>>choice;
            system("cls");
        }*/

        cout<<"Type N/n to Quit or Press Any Key and then Enter"<<endl;
        cout<<"Your choice? : ";
        cin>>choice;
        system("cls");
     }while(choice!='n' && choice!='N');

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, have a look at [`std::istream::clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and [`std::istream::ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: When posting code, please make it an  MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
Amongst other things, that would mean not including 20 lines of commented out code.  If the code is relevant, it won't be in a comment; if it isn't relevant, it shouldn't be in the question.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, pardon me if I'm wrong, actually I'm new to the community and still I don't know much about posting rules and regulations. As far as concerned to my question, I just place the relevant code into comments just because for debugging purposes.

Comment: Please, have a look at [tour] and [ask]. You will learn among other things: To react on a comment, you should address the commenter by prefix `@` and the name (you will get proposals on top left corner of comment field). This will notify the respective commenter. (Otherwise, your re-comment will probably be unnoticed.)

Comment: Thanks dear @Scheff for your valuable feedback, I would surely go through what you've suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) I believe the duplicate answers your question for invalid input (e.g. input of letters instead of digits). You still have to handle the case when user types an integral value which is out of range, additionally (your attempt in the currently commented code).

Answer (score 0):

Well your grade variable is an intteger, so it cant take any other type of variable. If you are going to input a char then why is grade an integer or if you are going to inout a string? If you need this to be possible then maybe try using arrays and start turning them from arrays to: integers floats booleans strings or characters. Also be careful because a char value can be assigned to a number (character  code).

Comment: Actually, that was my supposition that anybody can input a value other than an integer and in this situation my program should be efficient enough to not get crashed. Hence, I tried to validate the input but in vain.

Comment: BTW, I tried cin.clear() statement from the previous post and somehow it resolved my problem for now. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Well if you change the grade variable to string it can contain everything the user can enter, if there are only numbers you can check for that and convert to integer or float or double if necessary